# C Drive got filled while training my dataset over yolov5

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, training, pytorch, yolo

Asked the question over a cross-validated stack but got recommendations to ask at the data science stack. So, I recently bought a GPU and tried yolov5 on my personal dataset of around 1500 images. While **training** my C drive got filled (before that I had 11 Gb free). I am not sure what is the issue, but this might be the reason that I have python.exe in my C drive. If it's true, do I need to uninstall the python and reinstall it on another disk?

Comment: It might be useful to show how you are doing your training (i.e. post your script or commandline commands).
Also track down where on your disk the 11Gb has gone: temp files, or log files, or something else. After you'd downloaded the model, and just before training you still had 11Gb free? Or was it 11Gb before installing pytorch and the model?

Comment: @DarrenCook Ok i shall look up to it.